# What is ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, nsoperation

What is ASIHTTPRequest? how do we use it in an iphone application? what are the files we need to include? Does Apple provide files for this?

Comment: Some of these questions are answer in the wiki for the ASIHTTPRequest tag: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asihttprequest/info

Comment: How you accessed ' ASIHTTPRequest '  ?

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is [now deprecated](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;). You might want to look at the [FSNetworking](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2012/07/19/say-hello-to-fsnetworking-a-small-networking-library-for-ios-and-mac/) library that Foursquare released as a possible alternative.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read the **[ASIHTTP from here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)** you will be able to know what is it and how to use it....it is use to get the request from the server and post request to server

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

> #### What is ASIHTTPRequest?
>
> ASIHTTPRequest is an easy to use wrapper around the CFNetwork API that makes some of the more tedious aspects of communicating with web servers easier. It is written in Objective-C and works in both Mac OS X and iPhone applications.

—— from https://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 0):

A (BSD licensed) wrapper to facilitate the use of CFNetwork. Commonly, it is used to deal with HTTP requests.

The documentation explains how to use it. 
As ASIHTTPRequest is not an Apple product, Apple doesn't provide files for this.

This is what the [ASIHTTPRequest documentation page](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) says.

> ASIHTTPRequest is an easy to use wrapper around the CFNetwork API that makes some of the more tedious aspects of communicating with web servers easier. It is written in Objective-C and works in both Mac OS X and iPhone applications.

> It is suitable performing basic HTTP requests and interacting with REST-based services (GET / POST / PUT / DELETE). The included ASIFormDataRequest subclass makes it easy to submit POST data and files using multipart/form-data.

---

Also, ASIHTTPRequest page says
*Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)*

[RestKit](http://restkit.org) might be an alternative.